# Flatten Git tree with resolved merge conflicts to svn dcommit

Tags: git, svn

So I have a branch with a lot of merges that resolve conflicts. As such simply rebasing to flatten the history isn't time effective.

I need to flatten the history so that it can be committed to svn via dcommit (Other methods such as third party tools would be acceptable as well). Unfortunately I need to keep in tact the actual commits.

Is there a way I can flatten the tree so that it is linear in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wasn't able to come up with a way to do it directly in the time I had. I was able to use Github https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion to pull a svn friendly version and then rebase it on-top of the existing svn repo.